# How should I create my json classes to parse this with c#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've used several json to C# converters to generate classes so I can deserialize it with

```
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<someGeneratedType>(jsonString);
```

However I can't seem to get the results populated.  A **query-continue** object should have **usercontribs** which has **ucstart** which has a value.

Then I should get a **query** object which has 3 **usercontribs**.  I'd be much obliged if someone could help me figure this out.

```
{
  "query-continue": {
    "usercontribs": {
      "ucstart": "2013-07-18T02:24:25Z"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "usercontribs": [
      {
        "userid": "666777",
        "user": "UserYahoo",
        "pageid": 22255,
        "revid": 555566666,
        "parentid": 555577777,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Title A",
        "timestamp": "2013-07-16T01:13:32Z",
        "comment": "/* Comment A */",
        "size": 62789
      },
      {
        "userid": "666777",
        "user": "UserYahoo",
        "pageid": 22255,
        "revid": 564444444,
        "parentid": 555566666,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Title A",
        "timestamp": "2013-07-16T01:28:50Z",
        "comment": "/* Comment B */",
        "size": 62794
      },
      {
        "userid": "666777",
        "user": "UserYahoo",
        "pageid": 11777,
        "revid": 564333333,
        "parentid": 444499999,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Title B",
        "timestamp": "2013-07-17T03:28:50Z",
        "comment": "/* Comment C */",
        "size": 10865
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried removing the / characters that are in your comments?

Comment: Have you tried json2csharp.com? Seems to produce what you expect..

Comment: try something simpler and see if that works.

Comment: Removing the / doesn't work.  I've used json2csharp and it generates  an invalid property for the part of the RoobObject.  It does get the 3 usercontribs, but not the object that has the ucstart value.  I suspect the fact that each has a "usercontribs" object with differnt formats is the problem

Comment: @user3151958 I think if *usercontribs* are same objects then they should have same formats like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root element "query-continue" doesn't respond on named rules properties in C#. Most of deserializing sdk use the reflection, and in this case is impossible. 
I tested your sample without the dash on "query-continue" property and it's work fine.

```
public class Usercontribs
    {
        public string ucstart { get; set; }
    }

    public class Querycontinue
    {
        public Usercontribs usercontribs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Usercontrib
    {
        public string userid { get; set; }
        public string user { get; set; }
        public int pageid { get; set; }
        public int revid { get; set; }
        public int parentid { get; set; }
        public int ns { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string timestamp { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
    }

    public class Query
    {
        public List<Usercontrib> usercontribs { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Querycontinue querycontinue { get; set; }
        public Query query { get; set; }
    }
```

And i test it :

```
Stream fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\sample.txt");

DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
RootObject v_response = (RootObject)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(fs);
```

Comment: v_response.querycontinue is null when you run this

Comment: have you change the json string for delete the dash on query-continue ?

Comment: JSON can have a `-` in the property name.  To get it to work with Json.Net, you can add `[JsonProperty("query-continue")]` to the property in the class.